# OpenGL Shader - Edge detection with Frei-Chen Edge Detector

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I tried to create a shader that paints all edges black as you might know from [cel shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading). I've googled a lot and found many articles and source code how to create black outlines. Unfortunately, I do not understand most of them:

- I found this [article](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68401/how-can-i-draw-outlines-around-3d-models) about feature edge rendering and tried it like [this](http://in2gpu.com/2014/06/23/toon-shading-effect-and-simple-contour-detection/). Unfortunately, only the silhouette is black but not the edges that lie in the mesh. The same counts for [this article](http://in2gpu.com/2014/06/23/toon-shading-effect-and-simple-contour-detection/).
- Then I found [this](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2011/01/frei-chen-edge-detector/) article about Frei-Chen edge detector but I have no idea how this whole thing works, even after studying the description for quite a long while.

Could someone give me some help how to program such a shader?

EDIT: I do not use textures for my meshes.

Since I got a few downvotes for being too unspecific, I want to refer to Frei-Chen Edge detector. Here's the fragment shader code from [Rastergrid](http://rastergrid.com/blog/downloads/frei-chen-edge-detector/):

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D image;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
 {
mat3 I;
float cnv[9];
vec3 sample;

/* fetch the 3x3 neighbourhood and use the RGB vector's length as intensity value */
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
    sample = texelFetch( image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord) + ivec2(i-1,j-1), 0 ).rgb;
    I[i][j] = length(sample); 
}

/* calculate the convolution values for all the masks */
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    float dp3 = dot(G[i][0], I[0]) + dot(G[i][1], I[1]) + dot(G[i][2], I[2]);
    cnv[i] = dp3 * dp3; 
}

float M = (cnv[0] + cnv[1]) + (cnv[2] + cnv[3]);
float S = (cnv[4] + cnv[5]) + (cnv[6] + cnv[7]) + (cnv[8] + M); 

color = vec4(sqrt(M/S));
}
```

I skipped the G[9] matrix since this would blow up the code too much.
So I would very thankful if somebody could tell me how the assignment of

```
    color = vec4(sqrt(M/S));
```

should work since sqrt(M/S) returns a single float to a vec4()? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed if you read the GLSL specification. Construction of a `vec4` using a single scalar constructs a `vec4` with each component set to the scalar.

> **5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors**
>
> > Constructors can be used to create vectors or matrices from a set of scalars, vectors, or matrices. This includes the ability to shorten vectors.
> >
> > If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that scalar’s value

How this is useful, I could not say. Duplicating data across multiple channels of an image is a big waste of memory bandwidth...

Comment: "*Duplicating data across multiple channels of an image is a big waste of memory bandwidth...*" Fragment shader outputs are always 4-element vectors, even if the image they're ultimately bound for has fewer channels.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `gl_FragDepth` is a scalar fragment shader output, so I have a pretty hard time believing that. My point was more that if the shader is explicitly writing a `vec4`, it is likely the OP is using a 4 component image format. It would be better to swizzle a single component than explicitly write and read the same data.

Comment: That assumes the shader knows what image format its writing to. There's no reason why it should have to.

Comment: Definitely not, but the human who wrote the shader may know the format and may benefit from reading and writing a single scalar rather than conveniently duplicating it with a scalar `vec4` constructor overload. The OP had to ask how this constructor worked, I'm suggesting they ask themselves whether it is even the desired/necessary behavior here. I don't know anything about the image format or application in general, which is why I "could not say."